# Plain C - Array pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have structure to hold pointer to array of input numbers. When I create matrix I also create default data array. As I suppose the m.data = data; means that m.data pointer points at first element of the array. When I print data right after alocation everything seems ok. But when I print them after in the main function the result is different.
Why does output differs(commented sections)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct matrix {
    int *data;
    int rows;
} Matrix;

//Create Matrix
extern Matrix create_matrix(int size)
{
    int data[size * size];

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size * size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }

    Matrix m;
    m.data = data;

    for(i = 0; i < size * size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*(m.data + i)); //<--- m.data {0,0 ..... ,0,0,0}

    }

    m.rows = size;
    return m;
};

extern void supply_row_data(Matrix m, int row, int* data)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < m.rows; i++)
    {
        m.data[i] = data[i];
    }   
};

int main(){
    int size = 4;
    Matrix m = create_matrix(size);


    int i = 0;
    int *j = m.data;

    for(i = 0; i < size * size; i++)
    {
            //*(j + i) = i;

        printf("%d\n", *(j + i));
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `extern Matrix create_matrix(int size)` should be `extern Matrix *create_matrix(int size)`

Comment: @Mayerz Why? Is there a problem in returning a simple struct by value? That was a rhetorical question. There isn't.

Comment: Well the problem lies in the fact that the structure also contain a pointer, and this pointer isnt allocated. My comment was incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you can copy the data from an array in C.

You need to:

1. Allocate memory for the data.

   ```
   m.data = malloc(sizeof(int)*size*size);
   ```
2. Copy the data one element at a time or using `memcpy`.

   ```
   memcpy(m.data, data, sizeof(int)*size*size);
   ```
3. Make sure you deallocate the memory allocated to hold the matrix data.

   ```
   free(m.data);
   ```

Comment: `sizeof data` could be used for both `sizeof` expressions

Answer (score 3):

```
int data[size * size];
```

This is a local variable (array) to the function `create_matrix` It goes out of scope when the function terminates.

```
m.data = data;
```

This does **not** copy the data in the variable `data` to the data in the variable `m.data` but rather sets the pointer `m.data` to the beginning of the array `data`. When the function returns, the `Matrix` returned contains what is called a *dangling pointer*: a pointer to data that no longer exists.

Use the advice from @RSahu to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using pointer to local data once function return address of array is no loger valid try to allocate array in following way

```
int* allocate_vector(size_t elem, int value){
   int* vec = (int *) calloc(elem, sizeof(int));
   int i = 0;
   for( ; i < elem; i++){
      *(vec + i) = value;
   }
   return vec;
}
```